# Unable to print PHP error

Tags: php, error-handling

I am making use of [Chat-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API) to create my own WhatsApp client on a server. When I try to send a message, I don't even know if it has connected properly as no error at all is shown: screen is on white, and firebug does not show any info at all.

FYI I am newbie on this API and also on OOP so error could be quite basic.

As explained on [its Documentation](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation#connect-and-login-to-whatsapp), I have created a `conexionapi.php` file with this info (pwd and user have been removed due to security):

```
<?php
    require 'api/src/events/MyEvents.php';

    $username = "*****";
    $nickname = "ChatAPI tests";
    $password = "lHZhQ************"; // The one we got registering the number
    $debug = true;

    // Create a instance of WhastPort.
    $w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);

    $events = new MyEvents($w);
    $events->setEventsToListenFor($events->activeEvents); //You can also pass in your own array with a list of events to listen too instead.

    $w->connect(); // Connect to WhatsApp network
    $w->loginWithPassword($password); // logging in with the password we got!


?>
```

Following [documentation about sending a message](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation#sending-messages), I have tried that with this simple code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../conexionbbdd.php");
    include("../conexionapi.php");

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];   

    $ms_content = $_POST['ms_content'];
    $ms_img = $_POST['ms_img'];
    $ms_prefix = $_POST['ms_prefix'];
    $ms_phone = $_POST['ms_phone'];

    $w->sendMessage($ms_phone , $ms_content);
```

When the form is executed (I have alerted all variables and all cotain correct information), nothging happens: white screen, empty console.

I have tried

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

with no positive result. How could I get which PHP error goes on here?

Any additional code/info please ask.

Comment: put the error directives into php.ini, or at least .htaccess "php_value" directives, so they're in effect BEFORE your script starts getting parsed/executed. leaving them in the script proper means you'll never see any fatal errors that prevent the script from running in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I'll request it tomorrow, as I dont have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't directly turn on errors in the php.ini due to restrictions(this happened to me with Azure a while ago), you may need to put a .user.ini file in your root directory with the following:

```
display_errors = On
```

Note, that once you're issue is resolved you would want to turn off the error display for security reasons.